# Google Direction API returns error in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

Am using following google direction url

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=12.976600,77.599300&destination=12.991491,77.715347&client=gme-company&signature=Fwelfejfcb4bbb3hj5bb=
```

and its not giving any result

in browser its showing

```
Unable to authenticate the request. Provided 'signature' is not valid for the provided client ID, or the provided 'client' is not valid.
The signature was checked against the URL: /maps/api/directions/json?origin=12.976600,77.599300&destination=12.991491,77.715347&client=gme-company
If this does not match the URL you requested, please ensure that your request is URL encoded correctly. Learn more: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth
```

my method is this

```
 - (void) estimateETAWithWithOrigin:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)origin destination:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)destination onSuccess:(DirectionsCompletionBlock) completionBlock {


         NSString *baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&client=%@&signature=%@",
         GOOGLE_DIRECTIONS_API,
         origin.latitude,
         origin.longitude,
         destination.latitude,
         destination.longitude,
         CLIENTID,CRYPTO_KEY];
        baseUrl = [baseUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",baseUrl);


.....

}
```

Pls help

Comment: This is not iOS related.

Comment: check your client id and signature, both are same account?

Comment: that was crypt_key not signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find information on how to use digital signatures in the [developers documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key#client-id) 
You even have a place there to test your signature.
The code for signing a request in Objective C can be found [on the google maps github repo](https://github.com/googlemaps/url-signing/blob/gh-pages/urlsigner.m)